# Find Zeros / Factors of a polynomial

Tags: polynomials, roots

I have been told that to find factors of a polynomial (nth degree) we have to find the factors of constant term and that of coefficient of leading term of the polynomial in concern.

The possible integral zeros of the polynomial will be from the factor set of the constant term while rational zeros would be from set of each factor of constant / each factor of coefficient of the leading term.

Now I have to replace one by one value of $X$ for each integral and rational factors founded above and check if the polynomial results to $0$ (zero). The issue is that I go into deep / lengthy calculation if suppose constant term is $140$ and coefficient of leading term is $6$ per say.

Factors of $140 = -1,+1,-2,+2,-4,+4,-5,+5,-7,+7,.....$

Factors of $6   = -1,+1,-2,+2,-3,+3,-6,+6 $

Integral roots of the polynomial (set range) = $-1,+1,-2,+2,-4,+4,-5,+5,-7,+7,.....$

Rational roots of the polynomial (set range) 
= $(-1,+1,-2,+2,-4,+4,-5,+5,-7,+7,.....)/ (-1,+1,-2,+2,-3,+3,-6,+6 )$

Taking one by one value and testing for zero is a very lengthy time consuming method - is there a quick easy way to find zeros of the pronominal?

Comment: In general, finding the rational roots of a polynomial requires plugging in all of these values.  Some people automate the process using [synthetic division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic_division).  There are a few tricks in synthetic division that allow you to exclude possible values quickly, such as if the values on the bottom row are [always positive](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/synthtrk.htm).

Comment: The quick easy way to find zeros of a polynomial is to use the appropriate command in Maple or Mathematica or some other computer algebra package. Doing it by hand, I'm afraid that for every one of those rational numbers you refer to, there's a polynomial with constant term 140 and leading coefficient 6 having that rational solution and no other rtational solution.

Answer (score 0):

Using Descartes' Rule of Signs can give you every potential combination of positive, negative, and imaginary zeros for the polynomial. Using this can help clarify which factors which would be more likely for the given polynomial, and can help make your checking process more efficient.

Here is an example that has a leading coefficient of 6 and a constant of 140:

f(x)=6x<sup>4</sup>-x<sup>3</sup>+x<sup>2</sup>-x+140

This function has a total of 4 sign changes, meaning that the given polynomial can only have a maximum of 4 positive zeros.

Now plug in f(-x):

f(-x)=6x<sup>4</sup>+x<sup>3</sup>+x<sup>2</sup>+x+140

This function has a total of 0 sign changes, meaning that the given polynomial cannot have any negative zeros.

Because of this, you should only consider testing positive zeros.

The last thing that could help make the process more efficient is by using synthetic division as opposed to plugging in the possible zero and solving for it. Both methods take roughly the same time, but it is circumstantial and may end up being faster for specific functions.